# ¿Como obtener la estructura del xml del CFDI Carta Porte? en APS.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hola chicos estoy creando una solución en c# y ASP.NET de la carta porte tengo un ejemplo  de como se creo la estructura del xml para la versión 3.3 pero nunca he hecho algo similar y estoy confundido, por ejemplo ¿hay una forma de obtener el xml y mapearlo en c#? ¿Como empiezo a estudiar este tema (es decir que necesito saber para generar los campos del xml y como recorrerlos)? entiendo de que va el CFDI pero no se bien como hacer la implementación de la creación de generar xmls en c# o en .NET cualquier ayuda es agradecida

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital", IsNullable = false)]
```

Comment: Hola, yo estoy trabajando en algo asi, no se si ya lo hayas resuelto